# SOA - test algorithm 10^62 keys

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm working on a xor decryption algorithm and i need your feedbacks/helps.

I need to test 10^62 keys (4-8 chars alpha-numeric) with a string.

Key XOR string = **result**

If the decryption **result** contain real words, the key is ok and the algorithm is stopped.

**The problem is:**

I need to perform a quick test with all these keys, but it isn't possible to store this amount of keys, I need to perform volatile creation of these.

Have you got any purposes(snippets) about this hard problem? (I don't need the decryption function or dictionnary verification. Only the best way to apply keys XOR myString).

***I got 3 computers and SOA architecture.***

If you need some informations or missanderstand something, please tell me.

Comment: 3 computers may not be enough. Try buying 10^40 computers more.

Comment: @Kuba it will be much cheaper to use virtual machines. You'll only need 10^39 physical hosts then ;-)

Comment: @Michael What Kuba is getting at is that if your 3 machines can do a  trillion tests a second each, then it will still take [10^39 millenia](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=(10%5E62+%2F+3+trillion)+%2F+(3600+*+24+*+365+*+1000)) to process. Personally, I'm too impatient for that...

Comment: Ok. thanks for the fast answer (not possible so) ^^

Comment: Can't you generate parts of the key and check if it decrypts the corresponding key to printable characters? This would save you a lot of useless trial and error.

Comment: i think i can test over dictionnary words and add A-Z a-z 0-9 in front of the string or at the end. Can have 1 millions tests no?

Comment: How can 4-8 characters become 10^62 keys?

Comment: You will need at least 35 characters in your keys to get english upper and lower + digits (62 symbols) to give you 10^62 distinct key combinations. I think you need to go over your math on this one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for, is impossible in 2013 (and very probably even in 2014, 2015, ...)

Testing of an algorithm should be done under controlled conditions, not with all possible combinations.

For instance, you encrypt a series of texts/files with known keys, then decrypt them again with said keys, and test whether the output is the same as the original texts/files.

You may also try to decrypt with a different key, for instance one with a capitalized letter (like *Mykey* instead of *mykey*) and test whether that still decrypts, etc.

No way are you ever going to be able to test any sizable fraction of 10^62 keys.